# Trying to set up Visual Studio SQL Server Explorer and link it to an SQL Dbase on Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, database-connection

i'm a novice programmer am trying to set up Visual Studio Community, SQL Server Explorer, and link it to an SQL Dbase on Azure that i have just created, I used a .me address to setup the Azure account, when I try to connect to the Azure Dbase I can see it in the Visual Studio SQL Dbase connection list, using the same user name and pword as used for Azure but it throws up the error "Cannot open server "me.com" requested by the login. The login failed. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:40532), is this because i used an me.com account not a Microsoft account? Thanks to you all that take the time to help us novices. I'm on a PC running Windows10 home edition.

Answer (score 0):

When setting up a SQL Azure database it actually does not use the live id for the login for the connection string. It should have asked for a user name and password for the sql server login. You will need to use that instead.

This documentation explains how to set up the user:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started

Answer (score 0):

You will need to  go to Azure Management portal and create user name and password for your Azure SQL database then user that credential to login through server explorer in visual studio, you also need to install latest Azure SDK on your machine that gives you ability to view your Azure resources through visual studio. Also make sure you have SQl Server Data tool for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the replies, I could not get a connection, tried changing passwords and user names on my azure Dbase server but this made no difference. In the end I deleted the existing database and server from Azure and started again. Now i'm able to connect from Visual Studio. Not sure what went wrong but it is now sorted. Thanks